# My website code is being accessed by some other website. Same content are shown on real and dummy website

Tags: server, web-hosting, digital-ocean

I have hosted my website and it's working fine. But recently I found that there is some another website which is exact replica of my website.
When I stop my server it also stops working.
So, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

create a new droplet,copy your data from old to new one, point A records of the domain to the new IP and you should be through

Comment: That's what I had decided to do but just want to know if there is any other possible way to detect or correct it.
Thanks anyway.